# Trouble with a normal for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I was trying to make this small Fizzbuzz game using for loop. Here if the number is divisible by 3,5 or both 3 or 5 ,it's supposed to print FIZZ .But I'm not getting desired output. It's a simple for loop but i really can't figure out where's the problem.

Here's the code-

```
for i in range(1,101):
  if i % 3 == 0:
    print("Fizz")
  elif i % 5 == 0:
    print("Fizz")
  elif i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0:
    print("Fizzbuzz")
  else:
    print(i)
```

I'm not getting desired output, the output is irregular as well as number's are repeated too.

Comment: The condition in `if i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0` can never be true because you already ruled out `i % 3 == 0` and `i % 5 == 0` in the preceding if/elif statements.

Comment: `elif` stands for '__else__ if'. If one of the earlier conditions is met, you will never reach it.

Comment: Can u explain why?

Comment: Ohh okay i got this, so I'm supposed to use this elif   i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0: at  beginning of for loop, right?

Comment: `if` and `else if` are used when you only requiere one of them to be true. If the conditions don't contradict each other, use multiple `if's`.

Comment: @UzumakiPanda If you use `elif` at the beggining the program won't run. You need `if` before you can use `elif`

Comment: You don't mention "Fizzbuzz" in your problem description, so when should "Fizzbuzz" be printed? According to the description there is no need to ever output "Fizzbuzz".

Answer (score -1):

This is fairly straight forward.

```
for i in range(1,30):
    if i%3 ==0 and i%5 ==0:
        print(i,"fizzbuzzz")
    elif i%3 ==0 or i%5 ==0:
        print(i,"fizz")
    else:
       print(i)
```

Output:

1

2

3 fizz

4

5 fizz

6 fizz

7

8

9 fizz

10 fizz

11

12 fizz

13

14

15 fizzbuzzz

16

17

18 fizz

19

20 fizz

21 fizz

22

23

24 fizz

25 fizz

26

27 fizz

28

29

Comment: What is that code supposed to show?

Comment: did not notice that specific condition ...

Comment: This still does not solve a problem and your `elif` will never happen. If an alternative is false then conjuction will most certainly be false as well.

Comment: yes, please check now. @matszwecja

Comment: @Raytheyon_11 Yep, now it works. Although in original FizzBuzz game it's "fizz" on % 3 and "buzz" on % 5, for the question asked it works as intended.

Comment: I'm not certain Operator Precedence comes into play in any way here. It would if you had those operators in the same statement, but here they are not interacting with each other directly. It comes down to the order of statements you write.

Comment: `if` and `elif` are not functions, so you can drop the parentheses. `if (i%3 ==0 and i%5 ==0):` should just be `if i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0:`.

Comment: Understood @Matthias .

Comment: @matszwecja. Yeah got it .